# show that the IVP $x' = Ax + f(t),\,\,\ x(0) = x_0$ is transformed into a linear system of equations by the Laplace transform.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

show that the initial value problem

$x' = Ax + f(t),\,\,\ x(0) = x_0$

is transformed into a linear system of equations by the Laplace transform.

I have tried to apply the Laplace transform in both members of the equation and then use that $\mathcal{L} (x') (s) = s\mathcal{L} (x) (s) - x (0)$, but I can not find a linear system from there. Does anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: Do you not know what the Laplace transform of x' is?

Comment: Apply $\mathcal{L} (x') = \mathcal{L} (Ax + f(t))$, then $\mathcal{L} (x') (s) = s\mathcal{L} (x) (s) - x (0)= A\mathcal{L} (x) + \mathcal{L}f(t)$.  
But what guarantees that this is a linear system of differential equations? That is, if the correct resolution path is this.